# Modify Java file placeholder using maven

Tags: java, maven, placeholder

I call a web service which unfortunately it's namespace changes based on the server domain name. This make source control merging difficult and cause many builds to be erroneous. Can maven be used to replace a placeholder in java files for such variant variables? That will help me just to set the domain name of the server hosting the web service rather than modifying all files that contain the namespace.

Comment: instead of modifying source, why don't you generate different properties file for both build and let your source read that file to configure itself >

Comment: I used wsimport utility to generate the web service artifacts, all those artifacts are annotated and the annotations include the web service namespace. Replacing annotations values at runtime is not my option. So, I can't use properties files to store such configuration parameters

Comment: try exploring that plugin's source, if it already doesn't support fork it

Comment: Take a look at http://mojo.codehaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it by using the maven.

(1) Create a setting.xml file in your local maven repository. as mentioned below. 
http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

inside it you can create a different profile for your each server with different properties like below

```
<profile>
  <id>local</id>
  <properties>
       <hibernate.connection.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db</hibernate.connection.url>
       <hibernate.connection.username>db_user_name</hibernate.connection.username>
       <hibernate.connection.password>db_password</hibernate.connection.password>
  </properties>
</profile>

<profile>
  <id>dev</id>
  <properties>
       <hibernate.connection.url>jdbc:mysql://dev_url:3306/my_db</hibernate.connection.url>
       <hibernate.connection.username>dev_db_user_name</hibernate.connection.username>
       <hibernate.connection.password>dev_db_password</hibernate.connection.password>
  </properties>
</profile>

<profile>
  <id>production</id>
  <properties>
       <hibernate.connection.url>jdbc:mysql://prod_url:3306/my_db</hibernate.connection.url>
       <hibernate.connection.username>prod_db_user_name</hibernate.connection.username>
       <hibernate.connection.password>prod_db_password</hibernate.connection.password>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

**Note** : You can create any numbers of custom properties as per your requirement.

(2) 
inside the property file of your project's workspace. use the place holder instead of hard coded value. like db_connection_url =  ${hibernate.connection.url}

Assume property files exist at location : src/main/resources/*.*

(3) **Pom.xml** file set the "**filtering**" to true like below

```
<build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
</build>
```

(4) project build : use -P option, to specify the profile, which need to use when creating the project build file. for example

- when building for local server use the command : mvn **-P local** clean package
- when building for local server use the command : mvn **-P dev** clean package
- when building for local server use the command : mvn **-P production** clean package

Maven will use the appropriate profile and replace all the placeholders with define properties.

**Note** : You can define the  tag inside the pom.xml as well instead of creating the setting.xml file